# snprintf() warning and segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

I am newbie to C program. When I compiled the program, I got warning related to the snprintf() function and the compilation is completed. But when I run the binary file, I got segmentation fault. May I know is the segmentation fault related to the warning of snprintf? If yes, may I know how can I solve it?

Thank you.

```
../src/main.c:1924:54: warning: '%s' directive output may be truncated writing up to 99 bytes into a region of size between 0 and 999 [-Wformat-truncation=]
 1924 |                     snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "%s|%s", data1pld, data2ld);
      |                                                      ^~              ~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:867,
                 from ../../../src/porting/twLinux.h:17,
                 from ../../../src/porting/twOSPort.h:20,
                 from ../src/main.c:97:
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:67:10: note: '__builtin___snprintf_chk' output between 2 and 1100 bytes into a destination of size 1000
   67 |   return __builtin___snprintf_chk (__s, __n, __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1,
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   68 |        __bos (__s), __fmt, __va_arg_pack ());
      |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The program is

```
char temp[1000]="";
char data1pld[1000]=""; 
char ld[100]="";
char *ldb = malloc(100);  //"4331297.187"
strcpy(ld,ldb);
strcpy(data1pld,ld);
snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "%s|%s", data1pld, ld);
```

Comment: You allocate 100 bytes and store the pointer in ldb. The memory contains undefined contents at this point. You then strcpy(ld,ldb). If that malloc does not contain a '\0' within 100 bytes, then you will overrun ldb and ld memory. Need to initialize ldb. For example ldb[0]='\0'

Comment: @Chris, I will try it. 
I also get another the same issue. 

`#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{   char s1[100]="";
    char txtFilename[100];
    strcpy(txtFilename, "File_data_checking_415464324_444543.");
    snprintf(s1,sizeof(s1),"%scsv",txtFilename);
    strcpy(txtFilename,s1);
    printf("%s\n",txtFilename);
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}`

Comment: @Chris, The error is `/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:67:10: note: '__builtin___snprintf_chk' output between 4 and 103 bytes into a destination of size 100`
 When I run only that part in online C compiler, it gives the result. 
Is that kind of warning can be neglected? But in the whole C program, I receive 83 warnings and in the end when I run the binary file, I got segmentation fault.

Comment: Susan, this is not a forum. Please **add** new information to your question by [edit]ing it. -- No, you should **never** ignore warnings, the compiler emits them for a purpose. You have a problem in your code, solve it. Always use the maximum warning level and resolve any issue before going on.